# What could be making QGIS 2.10 crash when loading a project file?

Tags: qgis, layers, ubuntu, linux, qgs

On QGIS 2.10, running on Ubuntu 15.04 Linux, I have a project file that has a fairly large number of mainly shapefile layers, which gets to 99% on the slider to the right of where it has a message saying 'Loading layer *name of last layer*' and then just hangs there, for a long period of time (sometimes an hour) before the qgis process crashes.

I haven't had this fault before, even when working with other projects with large numbers of complex layers, and this fault affects one particular project file for no obvious reason.

I have already tried a couple of different methods of resolving this, firstly by removing this last layer by manually editing the .qgs project file in a text editor, and secondly by disabling all plugins and restarting qgis in case it could be a plugin causing the problem. Neither of these affected the issue. If I edit the .qgs file to remove the last layer, the program hangs instead as it displays 'Loading layer...' for the preceding layer.

I have no reason to think that the data of any of the actual layers are missing or corrupted, and in any case if this had happened I would have expected the "Handle bad layers" message instead.

Does anyone know what kind of situation is likely to have caused this, or how to remedy it?

Comment: Just a thought: after loading the layers, what is the next part inside the .qgs file? Maybe print composer collections cause the crash?

Comment: After all the layers, there is the <properties> section, which contained a few bits about a couple of plugins that I weren't using and not sure why the were in there. I deleted some of that, and also used "System Monitor" which showed that the memory usage when I tried loading the project, after it got stuck at 99% loading layers, steadily keeps increasing, until it reaches 100% and the system hangs.

Comment: I wonder if QGIS writes a log file as it loads...

Comment: Have you already [reported an issue](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index.html#bugs-features-and-issues)?

Comment: I am now strongly suspecting that what happened is I had a couple of big shapefiles, one of them with a .shp file of 1.2GB, joined to a text csv file of over 300MB, and I had duplicated this layer several times in order to have different variations on the styling ready as I have been experimenting with the visualisation. I suspect that somehow all those big joins overwhelmed the memory. In case you're wondering what I was doing have a look at my blog: http://skrifennow.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/indicating-curvature-layers-on-slope.html .